# If $x - \lvert x \rvert + \frac{1}{x} - \lvert \frac{1}{x} \rvert = 1$ then $x$ is irrational

Tags: calculus, irrational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For every real number $x$, if $x - \lvert x \rvert + \frac{1}{x} - \lvert \frac{1}{x} \rvert = 1$ then $x$ is irrational 
If $x$ equals $\sqrt{2}$ I get an inequality... So is this claim false?

Comment: When you write $\lvert x\rvert$, do you really mean something like $\lfloor x\rfloor$? The claim makes little sense with $|x|$ since $$ x-\lvert x\rvert = \begin{cases}0 & \text{when }x\ge 0 \\ 2x & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Let $f(x) = x - |x| + \frac{1}{x} - \left\vert \frac{1}{x}\right\vert$ then for $x > 0$ then $f(x) = 0$. For $x < 0$ then $f(x) < 0$. The claim is technically not false, but there is no real number $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: I don't think this would be true even if $| x|$ was replaced by $\lfloor x \rfloor$

Comment: This is reminiscent of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504381/proving-that-a-number-is-irrational except for the use of $|\cdot|$ instead of $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ (which is what I suspect the OP intended).

Comment: As noted by @HenningMakholm you have that it's equivalent to $2x + 2/x=1 \land x<0$, this makes it possible to solve the equation and you get a value that you can check for rationality. Then go see "proving that a number is irrational".

Answer (score 2):

No.  The claim is that if the claim is true then x is irrational.

The claim is *not* if x is irrational then the claim is true.

This is the sames as claiming "If x is a fish, it lives in water"  but a whale lives in water but isn't a fish, so it isn't true.

Comment: Turns out, the claim is more like "If $x$ is a unicorn, then $x$ lives in water." Since there are no such $x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Narwhal?

Comment: There are irrational x that solve the equation.

Comment: Oh, I just  realized that is absolute value.  The OP meant to type the floor function.  This was a duplicate and I had seen the other first.