# $x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor +\frac { 1 }{ x } -\left\lfloor \frac { 1 }{ x } \right\rfloor =1\implies x$ is irrational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor +\frac { 1 }{ x } -\left\lfloor \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right\rfloor =1$, then $x$ is irrational.

I am thinking of using the contrapositive: If $x$ is rational, then $x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor +\frac { 1 }{ x } -\left\lfloor \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right\rfloor \neq 1$

However, I don't know how I would approach this after that point. My first guess it to create a rational number, $\frac { a }{ b } $ such that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know how to manipulate it from there to get to the right hand side. I guess the floor function is throwing me off.

I would appreciate a hint/nudge in the right direction so that I can arrive at the solution by myself.

Comment: This question looks awfully familiar...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509734/if-x-lvert-x-rvert-frac1x-lvert-frac1x-rvert-1-then-x

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think you are talking about this link- http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1504381/177357

By the way, good find

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Good find. I spent a few minutes looking but couldn't find it...

Comment: @copper.hat Same with me lol.

Comment: Searching for latex works surprisingly good. Try for example searching for `\lfloor \frac 1x \rfloor` and all the similar questions comes up!

Comment: @copper.hat There are things in the answer there that I want clarified...unfortunately I can't comment there. Would you be able to clarify it for me, here?